# How to get unison to back up an entire file system starting at /?

Tags: linux, macos, sync, root, unison

I'm using `unison 2.52.1` both on my linux machine (Ubuntu version 20.04) and my Mac (MacOS version 11.7).

I want to use `unison` to back up my entire linux filesystem (excluding a few specific directories via "ignore") to a directory on the Mac via an ssh connection.

I know how to set up this ssh-based `unison` transfer except for one key point: it seems that `unison` is not permitting the initial "root" of the source machine to be `/`. However, since I want to back up everything on the linux machine, I need to start at the root of the linux filesystem tree.

Does anyone know of a way to get `unison` to allow the source "root" to be `/` under linux?

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**: Here is the preferences file which fails, and the error message that I receive ...

```
root = /
root = ssh://useronmac@thehost.com//Users/useronmac/backups
force = /
sshargs = -p 6543
[ "ignore" commands go here ]
```

This is the error I get ...

```
[ ...  etc. ... ]
Looking for changes
  Waiting for changes from server
Reconciling changes
         error            /  
The path / is a root directory
No updates to propagate
```

If I use any other name for the first "root" and for "force", it works fine. For example ...

```
root = /usr
root = ssh://useronmac@thehost.com//Users/useronmac/backups
force = /usr
```

That works with no problem.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Per @Edward's suggestion, I tried running with `-debug all`. Nothing particularly meaningful was printed beyond what I listed above.  Here are the significant stdout lines at the end of the `-debug all` output ...

```
[ ... etc. ... ]
[update] Updating archives
[update] Saving archive in /root/.unison/scb96ed4facff65e2345cb97206c90f055
[server: update] Saving archive in /Users/useronmac/Library/Application Support/Unison/scce5852e4685b7e41685f5f8f38d86e90
[update] Copying archive /root/.unison/tmb96ed4facff65e2345cb97206c90f055 to /root/.unison/arb96ed4facff65e2345cb97206c90f055
[server: update] Copying archive /Users/useronmac/Library/Application Support/Unison/tmce5852e4685b7e41685f5f8f38d86e90 to /Users/useronmac/Library/Application Support/Unison/arce5852e4685b7e41685f5f8f38d86e90
[update] Removing archive /root/.unison/tmb96ed4facff65e2345cb97206c90f055
[server: update] Removing archive /Users/useronmac/Library/Application Support/Unison/tmce5852e4685b7e41685f5f8f38d86e90
         error            /  
The path / is a root directory
No updates to propagate
Synchronization complete at 18:48:20  (0 items transferred, 1 skipped, 0 failed)
  skipped:  (The path / is a root directory)
[server: remote] Connection closed by the client
```

Also, I opened an issue on the `unison` github site, and soon thereafter, they closed it, telling me to read the entire `unison` docs and then to post any further questions on their mailing list. This implies to me that this `root = /` behavior is some sort of documented "feature", although I haven't yet found it mentioned in the docs ... although I haven't had time to read the entire documentation yet.

And I requested access to their mailing list, but I haven't been approved yet.

Anyway, I'll post whatever I find out from the `unison` docs and/or from their mailing list.

**YET ANOTHER UPDATE**

I couldn't find anything in the `unison` docs about `/` being prohibited as a "root". However, I started looking through the latest `unison` source code on their github site (https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison). It turns out that `/` is indeed hard-coded to be an illegal "root" under linux.

To see why I am making that claim, go to that `unison` github site and look at the `src/fspath.ml` file there. First of all, starting on line 45 of that file, we have this:

```
let isRootDir d =
(* We assume all path separators are slashes in d                            *)
  d="/" ||
  (Util.osType = `Win32 && Rx.match_string winRootRx d)
```

This says that on a non-Win32 OS, the `isRootDir` function returns "true" if the file in question is `/`, and it returns "false" otherwise.

Then, look at the `isRootDirLocalString` function starting on line 50 of that same file:

```
let isRootDirLocalString d =
  let d =
    if Util.osType = `Win32 then Fileutil.backslashes2forwardslashes d else d
  in
  isRootDir ((Fileutil.removeTrailingSlashes d) ^ "/")
```

This function also will return "true" on non-Win32 OS's for the `/` pathname.

Then, look at lines 380-382 of that same file:

```
if isRootDirLocalString realpath then
    raise (Util.Transient(Printf.sprintf
                            "The path %s is a root directory" abspath));
```

This code will raise an exception if the "realpath" variable is `/`, and you can see that the text of this exception is the exact error message that I get when I try to specify `root = /` in my tests.

There is no other place in the source code where this error message is printed.

Therefore, I am concluding that the prohibition of `root = /` is indeed some sort of intentional feature of `unison`.

Once I get onto the `unison` mailing list, I will ask if they would be willing to relax that prohibition if the "root" in question is tagged with "force".

Comment: I haven't checked this myself, but it sounds unlikely (to me, at least) that Unison wouldn't allow you to synchronize `/`. Could you share the error message you're getting?

Comment: See my "UPDATE" above. It shows the unison command which fails and it shows the error message.

Comment: `The path / is a root directory` ... that's an intriguing message. Is it an error message? Does unison think it shouldn't sync `/` for your own good? I'm not sure here. I'd recommend you [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues), asking what the intent here is. Be sure to come back here with an answer. I'm quite curious about this.

Comment: Well, after announcing that `/` is a root directory, unison says, "No updates to propagate", and it does nothing. So indeed it seems like unison doesn't want to deal with root as `/`.  But yes, I'll go to github and raise that issue, and then report back.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you omit `-force` ? (You will still have the option to abort unison before it starts making any changes.). And have you used `-debug all` ?

Comment: I have been afraid to omit `force = /` because I tend to be careless sometimes and make mistakes, and I don't want to trash my source machine by means of `unison` starting to overwrite or delete parts of my OS before I realize what I accidentally might have done. But maybe I'll get brave and try a quick `force = /` with a nearly immediate aborting of `unison`.  Also, I will soon try `-debug all` and report my findings. I'll report those findings above in an "ANOTHER UPDATE" section at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I looked through the `unison` source code on their github site, and I see now that `/` is indeed hard-coded as an illegal "root". See my "YET ANOTHER UPDATE" section in my question above for more details. (Also, in my previous comment, above, I should have written, "... maybe I'll get brave and try a quick REMOVAL OF `force = /` ...").

Comment: I found the answer! See my "Answer" below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer to my problem: upgrade to `unison 2.53.x` !

I had incorrectly thought that the `2.52.x` series was the latest, but it turns out that the `2.53.x` version has been released for at least a little while, and when I discovered that version and installed it on my hosts, I see that "root = /" along with "force = /" has now started working.

I guess that the unison folks also have recently realized that it's safe to use "root = /" along with "force = /".

Comment: Well you've just got an upvote for your detective work! Well done :) And I'm happy you got your problem solved.